# Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$quizUser

Tags: laravel

I run the laravel code for fetching the data from database but i got the error.

This is controller's code name is UserProfileController.blade.php

```
 public function FetchUserQus()
   {
     $data = DB::table('userquestion')->where('userEmail', '=', '{{ 
     Auth::user()->email }}');
     return view('designpages/userqus', ['data' => $data]);
   }  
     Route::get('designpages/userqus', 
    'UserProfileController@FetchUserQus')->name('designpages/userqus');
```

This is view page code saved with name designpages/userqus.blade.php

```
@foreach($data as $datas)

<p><b>Question:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{!! $datas->quizUser !!}</b></p>

<p><b>Answer:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>{!! $datas->ansAdmin !!}</p>
```

@endforeach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use blade syntax in the controller: So change this:

```
$data = DB::table('userquestion')->where('userEmail', '=', '{{ Auth::user()->email }}');
```

to this:

```
$data = DB::table('userquestion')->where('userEmail', '=', auth()->user()->email)->get();
```

And also I use `get()` to return a collection, without it it returns a `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` instance.

Comment: There's also the problem of no `->get()` on the query. I see you included it in your revised code, but it deserves a specific mention too in case OP misses that change.

Comment: tahnk u for help to all

Comment: @nakov Actually i am new on this site so don't how to do it.

Comment: There is a check mark next to the answer, so you click on it and it will turn from grey to green. Marking the answer as accepted.